# Compare content from a textfile in javascript

Tags: javascript, file-handling

I'm just trying to split textfile data into words and then comparing it but it don't return true.

```
var contents = e.target.result.split("\n");
if (contents[0] === "abc"])
    alert("abc=abc");
```

above is the simplest code i am trying to test but even on a single word it gives false. Help

Comment: that will split into lines, not words. and there is potentially spaces, tabs or \r characters, so you would want to trim each string.

Comment: there is something like js diff algoritham just look that http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/ it will help you

Comment: i have tried splitting further lines into words and comparing them but it also results in false, and yet only one word is in file i.e "abc" so spaces shouldn't be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Why you are placed `]` in your **if** condition after **"abc"**? Remove it

[**Reference**](http://jsbin.com/hucesilabi/1/edit)

```
 if (contents[0] === "abc"])
                          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just trying to split textfile data into words

Based on this, I'm assuming you actually want to split your text by whitespace, rather than just unix newlines (`\n`).  If that's the case, try passing a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for one or more consecutive whitespace characters (`/\s+/`), instead of `\n` as your separator:

```
var contents = e.target.result.split(/\s+/);
if (contents[0] === "abc")
    alert("abc=abc");
```

This will tokenize `e.target.result` using consecutive whitespace as separators.